# mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction deprecated and iOS 9

Tags: ios9, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

**WKWebViewConfiguration**:

- [`mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614727-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction) has been deprecated since iOS 9

  In `WKWebViewConfiguration`:

  ```
  @available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 9.0)
  open var mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: Bool
  ```

  And specified by Apple

  > **mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction**
  >
  > Deprecated property. Instead, use
  >   [mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor)

**WKWebViewConfiguration**:

- According to Apple's documentation [`mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor) is only for iOS 10+.

  In `WKWebViewConfiguration`:

  ```
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
  open var mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback: WKAudiovisualMediaTypes
  ```

**So here is my question:**

as `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` is deprecated for iOS 9, and `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` is only for iOS 10+, what can I use for iOS 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property on the `WKWebViewConfiguration` object you initialize your `WKWebView` with named `requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback`.

Comment: It was so obvious that I missed it... Thank you, you deserved your points! ;)

Comment: Yeah, my code (Objective-C) looks something like this now: ```if ( @available(iOS 10.0, *) )
    {
        configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( @available(iOS 9.0, *) )
        {
            configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = NO;
        }
        else
        {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
            configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    }```